# table row not high enough when using longtabu

Tags: tables, spacing, tabu, longtabu

I am using `longtabu` (`tabu` + `longtable`) in a file with many lines. There is large content filled in an `X` column. Sometimes (depending on the content of the column) the row ist made too tight (the padding doesn't apply and the letters touch the lower `\hline`).

Here is a minimal working example to demonstrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to 5cm {|X|}
  foo \\\hline
    asdfasfasfsadff asd asdfasdfsfsff asdff asdfff asdf asd\\\hline
    I am a long text but properly wrapped (why?)\\\hline
  bar\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first long line is just not high enough, so the letters touch the bottom line (see arrow), while the next line just works perfectly.

What's wrong with my code, why are some rows just not high enough for some content?

I can reproduce this with `pdftex` and `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

{
\tabulinesep = 5pt % <--- add space around horizontal lines
\begin{longtabu} to 5cm {|X|}
  foo \\\hline
    asdfasfasfsadff asd asdfasdfsfsff asdff asdfff asdf asd\\\hline
    I am a long text but properly wrapped (why?)\\\hline
  bar\\
\end{longtabu}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]