# Longtabu produces strange row heights

Tags: spacing, longtable, tabu, longtabu, strut

I would like to create a longtable using the longtabu environment from the tabu package. However, if the text in a column needs more than one line, the height of the corresponding row gets too small so that the text touches the horizontal lines of the table. Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| X | X | m{6cm} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Centered text in a multicolumn} & This text touches the horizontal lines of the table.\\
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Adding a `\strut` seems to fix the issue below the text, but it still touches the upper horizontal line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {| X | X | m{6cm}<{\strut} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Centered text in a multicolumn} & This text touches the horizontal lines of the table.\\
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

How can the spacing be fixed so that the text touches neither of the horizontal lines?

Comment: `tabu` as well `longtabu` are buggy and not maintained. They use is on your risk to have problems as you reported. Beter is to use for example `xltabular` package insted of `longtabu`,

Comment: try `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth} {| X | X | m{6cm} |}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Centered text in a multicolumn} & This text touches the horizontal lines of the table.\\
    \hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
`

Comment: You may also implement [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417232/9632) from @Zarko, if you insist using tabu. tabu was a promising project, but it seems that the author run out of time and interest.

Comment: The solution with xltabular works perfectly fine - I didn´t know that `tabu` and `longtabu` are no longer maintained.